# "Been seeing somebody doing something" vs "Saw somebody has been doing something"

Tags: grammar

> 1. I've been seeing him posting stuff on his blog
> 2. I saw he's been posting stuff on his blog

Which one sounds more natural? Do they mean the same thing to you? If they both are ungrammatical, how would you express this thought?

Comment: Provide context and describe the intended meaning.

Comment: user2684291, say you saw your friend post stuff on his blog yesterday, and today he posted again and then a few minutes ago you saw him post again. How would you form a sentence to tell somebody about this?

Comment: I would say it exactly as you said it. “He posted yesterday, and today he posted again, as well as a few minutes ago.” You haven't answered the second part of my question. However, let me now assume it's not important when your friend made a submission, but that he's done it repeatedly, and it took place recently in the past. “Lately, he's been posting on his blog.” If you want to emphasize on the fact that you [repeatedly] saw him post: “I’ve been seeing him post on his blog recently.”

Comment: Thanks for your input and making the question even more clear. Yes, I wanted to emphasize that I repeatedly saw him do it. Now it makes more sense to say "see him post" rather than "see him posting" as I certainly did not see him actually doing the action as if I was sitting next to him. Instead, I saw the post after he submitted it.

Answer (score 1):

Your first sentence is:

> I've been seeing him posting stuff on his blog

The word [see](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/see) has many possible meanings: among these are

- you observe something
- you are aware that something is happening
- you meet with somebody

When **see** is followed by a thing, the only valid meaning is  **observe**.

When **see** is followed by a person, two of these meanings are valid- **observe** and **meet with**.

When **see** is followed by a **that-clause**, the meaning **be/become aware of** are is valid.

If you are watching somebody, you can say "I see him", but people do not usually say "I am seeing him", because the use of a continuous tense of "see" implies the "meet with" meaning. So, you can say

> I saw him in the supermarket yesterday - observation
>
> I have been seeing my analyst for three years - meaning regular meetings
>
> I have been seeing John in Accounts - meaning you have been dating him (another form of regular meetings).

If you want to use a continuous tense meaning observing, you have to use "watch":

> I've been **watching** him posting stuff on his blog

This means that you were sitting next to him for a while, and he was posting stuff on his blog.

Moving on to your second sentence:

> I saw he's been posting stuff on his blog

If you observed him, you can't say "I saw **he**." you have to say "I saw **him**", because what you saw must be the object. For example,

> I saw him posting stuff on his blog.

When you say "I saw he...", it's really a **that-clause** where the **that** has been omitted. The omission is normal: you can tell that it's happened because the pronoun is a subject-pronoun. The complete sentence is therefore:

> I saw **that** he's been posting stuff on his blog

With a **that-clause**, the appropriate meaning is to "be/become aware of". The first part of the sentence therefore means that, at some time in the past, you became aware that he had been posting stuff on his blog. It's perfect simple- a completed action- so you aren't aware of posts since you last looked: the posting (as far as you are aware) finished before you became aware of it. you therefore should use past perfect continuous:

> I saw that he **had been posting** stuff on his blog.

If you are aware now that he is still posting on his blog, you should use the present simple:

> I **see** that he has been posting stuff on his blog.

If you have been keeping an eye on his blog for a while and are still doing so, you can use present perfect simple for "see":

> I **have seen** that he has been posting stuff on his blog.

Comment: JavaLatte, I could relate to your points, but how would you justify the verb to see in perfect continuous tense is almost limited to the meaning of "been dating with somebody" - convince me with examples like instead of "I've been seeing him smoking all day" how would a native speaker say it in a correct, natural way.

Comment: It's not confusing; “I've been seeing him do it” sounds natural and without the connotative meaning described and linked in this answer. Just the same, “I've been seeing him doing it” denotes a progressive property of the action. I.e. it implies the action has been observed throughout its duration.

Comment: @Jack, I have updated my answer to explain why you can't use the perfect continuous of "see" to mean "watch", and have included a link that shows some examples of each usage of "see".

Comment: JavaLatte, thanks again for your explanation. I see your points. Perhaps native speakers just don't say it that way.

Comment: @user2684291, it is common to use "I have been seeing" about observed things, for example the police might say "we have been seeing a lot of muggings in this area recently", but when you are talking about a person, the "meeting" sense is the more common usage- "I have been seeing a therapist".

Comment: @Jack, do you mean that native speakers don't say it your way, or don't say it my way? (I am a native English speaker, btw).

Comment: @JavaLatte I'm quite certain “I've been seeing him do something” is correct and acceptable with the meaning described in my comments. You may want to search for equivalently structured sentences online.

Comment: @user2684291 I'm not saying it's not correct, I'm just saying that it's not the most widely used way of expressing things. Try this: https://www.google.com.eg/search?q=I%27ve+been+seeing+him&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=_af2Vo_uOcXwUrblpsAM

Comment: @JavaLatte I concur. I think “watching” is a better (and unambiguous) alternative after all, and I apologize for favoring the equivocal one. I guess everything becomes an option after reading it too many times. Cheers!

Comment: JavaLatte, I mean perhaps they don't say it my way.

Answer (score 0):

They both sound fine, but hold slightly varied meaning.

(1) would typically mean that you've, on multiple occasions spread over the last little while, seen him post stuff on his blog.

(2) would indicate that you checked on it once, perhaps (but not necessarily) in preparation for this conversation, and noticed that he has recent posts.

These each contain examples of the Present Perfect Continuous ("have/has been seeing/posting"), which indicates an ongoing action that started some time ago. In the first, your ongoing action is seeing him post stuff. In the second, it's him actually doing the posting.

As for the Simple Past ("I saw"), that doesn't indicate ongoing nature, so we can assume that you just did it once.

Comment: Hi Matthew, thanks for your clear explanation. Would a native speaker ever say either of the sentences? Btw, I've added more details to my question in the comment above. Thanks.

Comment: @Jack Yeah, definitely! Those sentences are both perfect. I'd be a little tempted to say "I've been seeing him *post* stuff on his blog," but definitely for day-to-day speech, I would readily accept either without as second thought.